# UTF-8 characters corrupted when plotting with base R

Tags: r

I am trying to plot UTF-8 characters using base R plotting and Quartz in a Mac environment. My problem is that most of the UTF-8 characters are plotted as unfilled rectangles.

For example, the following code

```
xy = expand.grid(1:10,10:1)
pch=c(-(9632:9727),rep(NA,4))
plot(xy[,1],xy[,2],pch=pch)
```

produces

[image]

The expected symbols can be found here

https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_geometric.asp

I am using R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01) -- "Bird Hippie" on MacOS Monterey v12.1

Thanks!

Comment: The rectangles are NULL symbols, which your font uses as a fallback when it doesn't have a glyph for that particular symbol. Your font simply doesn't support these particular glyphs.

Comment: Thanks @AllanCameron, is there anyway to change the plotting font and which ones might be compatible with the suite of UTF-8 symbols?

Comment: You could try Segoe UI Symbol